# Is it possible to append objects to the same layer as they are in the source file?

Tags: append, layers

When appending objects to new .blend file, is it possible to make objects to retain their original layers?

Comment: Do you mean you want them to all append on the same layer, or for each object to append on a different layer?

Comment: Sorry, each object on the same layers that stay in the previous blend file. always, when I append the blender file, the objects append all in the one layer only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click append, select all your objects then in the lower left hand corner, there should be an option panel. Untick the *Active Layer* option.

[image: active layer]